# bootstrap modal window not showing modal box when layer slider is activated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

i'm working on wordpress with bootstrap theme.i have a modal box at homepage which loaded when we open the page.everything working fine but when i acivate the layer slider plugin for wordpress from codecanyon the modal window stop working.only the window background is appearing without any modal box. how can i remove this confliction.

Here is my code for modal window with modal box:

```
<div id="openHouse" class="modal hide fade abc">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> x </button>
<div class="well"><a href="http://pearlacademy.com/mumbai-career-conclave-2/"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/career_conclave_banner.jpg" id="image" /></a></div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#openHouse').css('width',"870px");
    $('#image').css('height',"400px");
    $('#openHouse').css('margin-left',"-430px"); 
    $('#openHouse').modal('show');
});
// ]]></script>
```

when i have activte the layer slider plugin then on seeing it by firebug it only shows this code:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

here is the whole code on my page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">

[include-page id="9917"]
<div class="visible-phone">
<div class="accordion-heading" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a class="accordion-toggle" style="color: 5e5e5e;" href="http://pearlacademy.com/noida-campus/">Noida</a></div>
<div class="accordion-heading" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a class="accordion-toggle" style="color: 5e5e5e;" href="http://pearlacademy.com/jaipur-campus/">Jaipur</a></div>
<div class="accordion-heading" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a class="accordion-toggle" style="color: 5e5e5e;" href="http://pearlacademy.com/chennai-campus/">Chennai</a></div>
<div class="accordion-heading" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a class="accordion-toggle" style="color: 5e5e5e;" href="http://pearlacademy.com/delhi-campus/">Delhi</a></div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px;"><a href="http://pearlacademy.com/admissions/"><img title="Pearl Academy ranked Second" alt="Pearl Academy ranked Second" src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/admissions.jpg" /></a></div>

<div style="margin-top: 20px;"><a href="http://pearlacademy.com/second-amongst-indias-best-fashion-college-2013/"><img title="Pearl Academy ranked Second" alt="Pearl Academy ranked Second" src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Pearlon2rank.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
<!--# Span 3 Ends-->
<div class="span9 visible-desktop">[include-page id="9894"]
[include-page id="9896"]
<!--#  carousel Ends--></div>
<!--# Span 9 Ends-->

</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="openHouse" class="modal hide fade abc">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> x </button>
<div class="well"><a href="http://pearlacademy.com/mumbai-career-conclave-2/"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/career_conclave_banner.jpg" id="image" /></a></div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#openHouse').css('width',"870px");
    $('#image').css('height',"400px");
    $('#openHouse').css('margin-left',"-430px"); 
    $('#openHouse').modal('show');
});
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue your WP scripts. Your JS is being parsed as XML, hence `// <![CDATA[` I am assuming that you are copying your JS directly to the content area of your page or post?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#openHouse').css('width',"870px");
    $('#image').css('height',"400px");
    $('#openHouse').css('margin-left',"-430px"); 
    $('#openHouse').modal('show');
});
// ]]></script>
```

How to enqueue WP scripts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @ JHuangweb :yes i have put my js direct into my page and its working nice until i have activated the wp layer slider plugin. can u hlp me on my problem that what should i do to work both.

Comment: Can you post your entire page source on jsFiddle? It's really hard to what else is going out without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: @ JHuangweb : sorry bro i dont have an account on jsfiddle but there is just pure html code in my page i will put that in my edited question. evrything was working good until i activated the wplayer lsider plugin.

Comment: @Monty, you are still pasting the code that is in your WP content area.  Please go to preview page, view source and post all that is there.   Also, you don't need an account to post on jsfiddle.